# Dialog with data from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, dialog

I have a list view of Hotels and I want when the user clicks a long click on an item a dialog appears with the information of the clicked hotel retrieved from the SQLite database (Location, Address, Phone number...etc.).
I retrieve data from the database in a List.
In the dialog message when I convert the list toString() the result has extra square brackets, example: Phone: [02239348], what should I do? Is there another way?

Here is the code from DataSource.java which retrieves the location from database:

```
 public List<Hotel> getHotelLocation(String hotelName) {
    List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<Hotel>(); 
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_Hotel, 
            hotelsLoc, hotelsNames[0] + " like " + "'" + hotelName + "'", null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Hotel hotel = cursorToHotel(cursor);
        hotels.add(hotel);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return hotels;
}

private Hotel cursorToHotel(Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Hotel hotelname = new Hotel();
        hotelname.setName(cursor.getString(0));
    return hotelname;
}
```

Here is the alert dialog:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String hotelName = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();
    List<Hotel> location = datasource.getHotelLocation(hotelName);
    String loc = "Location: " + location.toString();
    List<Hotel> address = datasource.getHotelAddress(hotelName);
    String add = "Address: " + address.toString();
    List<Hotel> rating = datasource.getHotelRating(hotelName);
    String rat = "Rating: " + rating.toString();
    List<Hotel> phone = datasource.getHotelPhone(hotelName);
    String phoneN = "Phone: " + phone.toString();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Information about " + hotelName);
    builder.setMessage(loc + "\n" + add + "\n" + rat + "\n" + phoneN + "\n");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please modify on my code? I don't know which parts to modify

Comment: Can you please post the source for your Hotel class? I'd like to see what the getHotelPhone method does.

Comment: public List<Hotel> getHotelPhone(String hotelName) {
  List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<Hotel>(); 
  Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_Hotel, 
    hotelsPhone, hotelsNames[0] + " like " + "'" + hotelName + "'", null, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
   Hotel hotel = cursorToHotel(cursor);
   hotels.add(hotel);
   cursor.moveToNext();
  }
  // Make sure to close the cursor
  cursor.close();
  return hotels;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either join the lists into a String with `TextUtils.join(", ", theList)` or you can simply use the first item of your list (`theList.get(0)`) if that is enough.

```
List<Hotel> phone = datasource.getHotelPhone(hotelName);
String phoneN = "Phone: " + TextUtils.join(", ", phone);
```

if phone has multiple entries it should print `"Phone: 12343, 3424323, 19393"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the toString() method for a List and the default implementation for that List probably uses the "[" elements "]".

Do you want to print the first element of the List? Just override the toString() at your Hotel class them you can use

```
phone.get(0).toString()
```

Regards